# Redirect ALL Traffic to single page if a domain matches

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a simple hosting account, and the folder structure is as follows:

```
/ (web root)
|
|-domain1
|-domain2
|-domain3
|
...
```

Due to some server migrations going on, I needed to have a real domain pointed at the web root, let's say `domain0.com` with or without the `www`

I need an .htaccess file that forces all access to `index.php` page when you access `http://domain0.com/` For example, you would be unable to render `domain1's` website by loading `http://domain0.com/domain1/` and instead be forced to go to `http://domain0.com/index.php`

I have tried writing it on my own, but keep blowing up the server with bad redirects. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own redirects were most likely recursively redirecting to the index.php. You need to block the rule for that script, so it isn't run on that page request, e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain0\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,R]
```

This should be put above any conflicting RewriteCond/Rule's, so they wont interfere with the redirection.

Any .htaccess files in subdirectories will by default remove this rule and not do the redirect. To fix them, you must add either the rule again to them, or set them to inherit from parent .htaccess files, e.g.:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Comment: This works for most requests, but if I make a request to a known file `http://(www.)domain0.com/domain1/index.html` it will render `domain1's` index page. How can I prevent this to redirect everything?

Comment: Are there any other RewriteRules in the .htaccess? I'm guessing there is another rule that is interfering. To get the correct fix, I'd need to see all of it.

Comment: If you place the rule above the others, it should solve the problem.

Comment: I have only these rules (plus rewrite on) in the .htaccess file. It is in the root directory `/`

Comment: Do these domain1.com websites do some automatic rewriting of their own, e.g. going to http://domain1.com/ serves /domain1/?. If so, there is probably a RewriteRule inside the apache config itself that is doing this. Your only solution then would be to add the conds/rule to each domain's path as well.

Comment: Ah yes, some subdomains have their own `htaccess` settings. So if I understand this correctly, I would also need to catch it on that level too (if coming from domain0) ?

Comment: Yes, that would be why. Actually, you might just need to add to those .htaccess just: RewriteOptions inherit. This will mean they will also use the base .htaccess rules as well

Comment: Andy thank you so much! I request that you update your answer to mention the need to fix sub `.htaccess` files and the final result. I would be MORE than happy to mark your answer correct. I have put my notes up here: http://pastie.org/1390291 for a working project

Comment: Corrected link: http://pastie.org/1390315